# preventDefault is stopping propagation?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using legacy .NET Web Forms, I have a scenario where the user wants to calculate values when pressing the enter key in a given textbox.  This works fine, however, the enter keypress is also firing the default form submit button on the page.

I have tried to get around it by adding `event.preventDefault()` and `return false` to the textbox's event handler, but the form is submitting prior to the event occurrence so this code has no affect.

```
$("input[type='text']").keypress(function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        var regionId = $(this).attr("data-region-id");
        var subRegionId = $(this).attr("data-subregion-id");
        var multiplier = $(this).val();
        CalculateSales(regionId, subRegionId, multiplier);
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
});
```

After reading a bit more, I learned that I could attach an event handler to the default form and use `preventDefault()` to allow propagation of events:

```
$("#form").on("keyup keypress", function(e) {
    var code = e.keyCode || e.which; 
    if (code  == 13) {               
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

With this method, the form is not submitted, but the input keypress event is not handled.  How can I ensure that the form is not submitted but also the input keypress calculates the values?

Comment: I think you're looking for [stopPropogation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)

Comment: If you want to stop submission, perhaps you should consider the [`submit` event](https://api.jquery.com/submit/)?

Comment: this works for me in Chrome in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jgsp1ory/

Comment: So to resume, you want to prevent FORM submitting when `return` pressed on any child input??? Does the keypress event fired? What have you try to debug your code?

Comment: What does `CalculateSales` do? Are you sure that function actually works correctly?

Comment: I'm positive CalculateSales works correctly.  A breakpoint at the event code check is never hit, so the function is not being executed despite the handler being registered on pageLoad. Rhumborl's fiddle is how I have the code set up (which works), but the functions are split between a master page and child control, so I'm sure there's some legacy, awful code preventing it from working normally.  Thanks all. Will update with resolution

Comment: @TimeBomb006 So you have to delegate event... http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/  Really next time, try to find a more relevant title, it doesn't really make sense regarding your issue

Answer (score 0):

No, `preventDefault` is not stopping propagation. These two functions have quite different functionality.

`stopPropagation` stops the event from going up the event chain.

`preventDefault` prevents the default action in the event inside which it is called. However, the event **still propagates** up the chain.

`return false` is equivalent with calling both `preventDefault() and stopPropagation()`. However calling the functions is the preferred way because you can call them at the start of the function. `return false` can be obviously used only at the end, and and error would prevent it from running.

This is why most of the time you end up using both these functions in conjunction.

Such is your case here, **you have to use both**.

```
$("#form").on("keyup keypress", function(e) {
    var code = e.keyCode || e.which; 
    if (code  == 13) {               
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
    }
});
```

Comment: Following OP's comment, issue is regarding event not fired. You were misled due to so bad question title

Comment: It's not only the title. It's also "After reading a bit more, I learned that I could attach an event handler to the default form and use preventDefault() to allow propagation of events". That's a false statement so I felt the need to clear it up.

Comment: Oh ya, many things seem wrong in question indeed, wrong statements/assumptions, not enough context, not enough info regarding debugging, etc...